# I want my drop down also work as a link in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html

While I am clicking this dropdown menu it's not going to the product section it's only expanding the menu and showing me Single-phase and three-phase but not also going to the product section that I made. Currently, I am using Bootstrap 5

Here is the code:(for navbar)

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown a-group">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
        data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" href="#product">
        Products
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li><a class="nav-link dropdown-item" href="#">Single Phase</a></li>
        <li>
            <hr class="dropdown-divider">
        </li>
        <li><a class="nav-link dropdown-item" href="#">Three Phase</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Here is product section:

```html
<section id="product">

    <div class="container">
        <header class="section-header">
            <h3><b>Check out our products!</b></h3>
        </header>

        <div class="carousel">
            <div id="carouselExampleInterval" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active justify-content-center" data-bs-interval="10000">
                        <img src="image/intro-one.png" height="500px" class="d-block" alt="...">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <h5>First slide label</h5>
                            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item justify-content-center" data-bs-interval="2000">
                        <img src="image/intro-two.png" height="500px" class="d-block " alt="...">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <h5>First slide label</h5>
                            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item justify-content-center">
                        <img src="image/intro-one.png" height="500px" class="d-block" alt="...">
                        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                            <h5>First slide label</h5>
                            <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleInterval"
                    data-bs-slide="prev">
                    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
                </button>
                <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleInterval"
                    data-bs-slide="next">
                    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `data-bs-toggle="dropdown"` and add style for hover

```css
.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">




<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://google.com" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li> 
    </ul> 
  </div>
</nav>
```